# Get the ordinal position while creating selected Item in a LINQ expression

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, ordinals

How can I get the ordinal position while creating selected Items in a LINQ expression? For example:

```
var alphaordinals = new string[] { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" };  // etc.
var q = from car in datacontext.Cars
        select new InventoryItem
        {
            Name = car.Name,
            Price = car.Price,
            UIElement = "Car " + car.Id.ToString() + ???                        
        };
return q.ToList();
```

I want the **InventoryItem.UIElement** of the list of Cars to be like :

```
Car 27 A

Car 28 B

Car 31 C

Car 48 D
```

etc.

Comment: By the way, alphaordinals could be a character array rather than a string array: `string alphaordinals = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the overload of `Select` which provides the index as well as the value. In this case I'd use `AsEnumerable` to get out of the database context, which isn't really where you want to be doing this work:

```
string[] alphaOrdinals = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" };
var query = dataContext.Cars
                       .AsEnumerable()
                       .Select((car, index) => new InventoryItem { 
                                  Name = car.Name,
                                  Price = car.Price,
                                  UIElement = string.Format("Car {0} {1}",
                                                            car.Id,
                                                            alphaOrdinals[index])
                               }).ToList();
```

(You can change `alphaOrdinals` to a string without any other change to the code, btw.)

Comment: what is the standard linq equivalent of .Select((car, index) =>

Comment: @Batu: If by "standard linq" you mean "query expression", there isn't one.